# Addition images opencv (line road detection)

Tags: python, opencv, line, detection

I hope everyone is doing well,
I am working on a road lane detection project (white marking on the road), and I need to apply a pre-processing to the images before the detection, this pre-processing is the addition of successive images (10 img for example).

My objective is: Apply an algorithm which adds the successive images of the chosen image base, then save the result in a new base.
I only have one  information which is:
The equation used to addition successive images is:
I(k)=max{ I(k-1), I(k-2), ...., I(k-p) }

I(k) is the image at time k. P is the number of successive images to be added.

I used Python programming language and OpenCV library.

Here is the first code I made to download and display the images from the database which contains 60 images:
download images:

```
images = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob("drive/MyDrive/Test1_lane_detection_/BDD/*.png")]
```

Display the images:

```
    def list_images(images, cols = 4, rows = 15, cmap='gray'):

    for i in range(0, len(images), rows*cols):
            plt.figure(figsize=(50,50))
            for j in range(0, rows*cols):
                    plt.subplot(rows, cols, j+1)
                    plt.imshow(images[i+j], cmap = cmap)
                    plt.axis("off")
                    plt.xticks([])
                    plt.yticks([])
                    plt.tight_layout(pad=0, h_pad=0, w_pad=0)        
            plt.show()
```

list_images(images)

Here are 5 images from the database:
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2O6A.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bv1w.png
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lFbL.png
[6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5B7Q.png
[7]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPUBJ.png

And here is an example that shows the result I will try to achieveso, the goal is to improve the white markings and avoid discontinuous markings :
This image represents, on the left the original image and on the right after the addition of 10 successive images:
[8]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/69h0K.png

Comment: could you post your code?

Comment: Hello, i posted the code

Comment: `range(0, len(images), rows*cols)` you are iterating over len(images) with a step of size rows*cols? this seems wrong.